# How to adapt a text to an elliptic textarea or text input element

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, css-shapes

I want to develop a comic editing tool in html php and js (jQuery UI), and I need a way to make the text automatically adapt to the speech bubble, which is an elliptic textarea or a text input (with `border-radius = 50%`).
I found many things around css-shapes, but it looks like `shape-inside`, which would have been perfect for my case, isn't working (anymore?).
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hey can you maybe post your attempt?

Comment: you could try using shape outside instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside

Comment: I've thought about it, but I would prefer an efficient way, if it exists. Using `shape-outside` would require a lot of calculations, compared to what `shape-inside` was supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

The Demo has:

- `contenteditable` fieldsets
- Different classes for yelling and thinking
- Uses `fit-content` to conform with its content and **expands while user is typing.**

### Demo

```css
.bubble {
  font: 400 100%/1.5 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 45%;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: .75em 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.thought {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
}

.YELL {
  font: 400 1.5rem/1.1 Impact;
}

.YELL legend {
  font-family: Arial
}

.speak {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.8em;
}

.fromCenter {
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(160deg)
}

.fromLeft {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.fromRight {
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(60deg)
}

.rightPanel {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter" rel="stylesheet">

<fieldset class='bubble YELL rightPanel' contenteditable>
  HULK SMASH!!!
  <legend class='speak fromCenter'>&#923;</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='bubble' contenteditable>
  My spidey sense is tingling!
  <legend class='thought fromLeft'>Ooooo</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='bubble' contenteditable>
  I'm the best there is at what I do,<br> but what I do best isn't very nice.
  <legend class='thought fromRight'>Ooooo</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is interesting, I might use this if I don't find a way to do what I want, which is to make the text adapt to the ellipse, which size is actually editable, and not the other way around.

Comment: I see, maybe try something along the lines of a borderless textarea overlayed on a SVG or canvas?

Comment: I would like to do something kind of like this, but I actually don't need the visual... Which makes it easier... : [https://phraseit.net/]